# Model issue using jsonschema2pojo

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, jsonschema2pojo

I have started to use retrofit to work with json, using jsonschema2pojo to generate my models. But i faced a problem that one field in Json can be array as well as object. Can somebody give me advise how to solve this?

Comment: What does that even mean? Do you mean an array of objects?

Comment: I mean it can be a single Jsonobject( {}, ) or JsonArray([{},{},...],).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. If there is a multiple choice beetwen array or object, need to change problem field class to JsonElement, change args in setters,getters and the model will be created and avalible to use.